# Failed to convert string to tuples when using pynput

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a csv file in which i got some coordinates like this

```
Type,Button,Coordinates,WaitTime
Press,Button.left,"(1078, 1069)",0.3
Release,Button.left,"(1078, 1069)",0.0
Press,Button.left,"(1450, 1062)",0.3
Release,Button.left,"(1450, 1062)",0.0
```

and what i am trying to do is get the csv read the input and by using pynput library click on coords.

```
for run in range(self.runTimes): 
            rows = self.keyEvents[self.skipFirst:]
            if run == 0:
                rows = self.keyEvents
            for i, row in rows.iterrows():
                sleep(row.WaitTime)
                row.Coordinates = eval(row.Coordinates)
                # print(type(row.Coordinates))
                if type(row.Coordinates) is tuple:
                    mController.position = row.Coordinates
                    if row.Type == 'Press':
                        mController.press(row.Button)
                    elif row.Type == 'Release':
                        mController.release(row.Button)
                else:
                    row.Button = row.Button.replace("'","")
                    if row.Type == 'Press':
                        kController.press(row.Button)
                    elif row.Type == 'Release':
                        kController.release(row.Button)
```

I tried to convert the `str` which was in the file when we read the cords i am converting it to tuples using `eval()` function but that doesn't seems to be working out here.

Here is my console error -

```
<class 'tuple'>
(1078, 1069)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\quickrpa.py", line 232, in play
    mController.press(row.Button)
  File "C:\Users\Beast-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pynput\mouse\_base.py", line 90, in press
    self._press(button)
  File "C:\Users\Beast-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pynput\mouse\_win32.py", line 110, in _press
    dwFlags=button.value[1])))),
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'value'
```

it does accept value rather than a string

```
>>> from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller
>>> mouse = Controller()
>>> x= 'Button.left'
>>> mouse.press(x)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Beast-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pynput\mouse\_base.py", line 90, in press
    self._press(button)
  File "C:\Users\Beast-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pynput\mouse\_win32.py", line 110, in _press
    dwFlags=button.value[1])))),
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'value'
```

using a converter

```
        def mouse_button_convertert(text):
            if text == "Button.left":
                return Button.left
            elif text == "Button.right":
                return Button.right

        for run in range(self.runTimes): 
            rows = self.keyEvents[self.skipFirst:]
            if run == 0:
                rows = self.keyEvents
            for i, row in rows.iterrows():
                sleep(row.WaitTime)
                row.Coordinates = eval(row.Coordinates)
                print(type(row.Coordinates))
                print(row.Coordinates)
                if type(row.Coordinates) is tuple:
                    mController.position = row.Coordinates
                    if row.Type == 'Press':
                        mController.press(mouse_button_convertert(row.Button))
                    elif row.Type == 'Release':
                        mController.release(mouse_button_convertert(row.Button))
                else:
                    row.Button = row.Button.replace("'","")
                    if row.Type == 'Press':
                        kController.press(row.Button)
                    elif row.Type == 'Release':
                        kController.release(row.Button)
```

it throws a diff. error AttributeError: 'App' object has no attribute 'Button'

Comment: @PatrickArtner Thanks for quick help i just did the changes but however it seems to be correct

```<class 'tuple'>
(1078, 1069)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\quickrpa.py", line 232, in play
    mController.press(row.Button)
  File "C:\Users\Beast-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pynput\mouse\_win32.py", line 110, in _press
    dwFlags=button.value[1])))),
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'value'```

Comment: `row.Button` seems to be a string taken from the csv with a (string) content of `'Button.left'` - where do you convert that to something that might have a `.value` accessor than is being used inside `kController.press("Button.left")` ?

Comment: @PatrickArtner yup you are correct just checked in console it does accept value rather than a `str`. I updated it in above issue. in this case can you suggest me how i can convert str to value here.

Comment: @PatrickArtner I get a weird error upon that AttributeError: 'App' object has no attribute 'Button' if i return button directly as that button is defined in pynput.  If you can give one more hint that will be helpful in this case.

Comment: Thats because your "App" has also a class named Button - you can distinguish between both buttons by importing one under a special name: `from pynput.mouse import Button as mouse_button` - see edit in answer below

Comment: @PatrickArtner as per this code it will correct the button but those values are not actionable it will pass the button.left and pynput will drag the mouse there but it will not click on that location.

`if row.Type == "Press":
 try:
        mController.press(mouse_button_converter(row.Button))
 except:
        mController.press(row.Button)`

I did it like this in case if it's in live replay mode then it will execute the old one directly as they are in correct format
i printed the row.Button and output seems to be correct

`PressButton.right
ReleaseButton.right
PressButton.left'

Answer (score 0):

Create a converter from string to correct type:

```
def mouse_button_converter(text):
    from pynput.mouse import Button as mouse_button

    if text == "Button.left":
        return mouse_button.left
    elif text == "Button.right":
        return mouse_button.left 
    elif text == "Button.middle":
        return mouse_button.middle
    return mouse_button.unknown
```

and use the converted value in

```
 kController.press(mouse_button_converter(row.Button))
```

as it only accepts `Button` objects and `row.Button` is a string of what you want it to press.

Answer (score 0):

It was way too much pain using pynput but I am still open for answers or any suggestion in the mid on offchance i used pyautogui for resolution of this issue.

```
if type(row.Coordinates) is tuple:


mController.position = row.Coordinates
                if row.Type == 'Press':
                    try:
                        # mController.press(mouse_button_converter(row.Button))
                        mController.press(row.Button)
                    except:
                        if 'left' in row.Button:
                            pyautogui.click(button='left')
                        else:
                            pyautogui.click(button='right')
                        # mController.press(row.Button)
                elif row.Type == 'Release':
                    try:
                        mController.release(row.Button)
                        # print('.')
                    except:
                        pass
```

kinda does the trick out of the box but still not a proper answer.